# can i keep duplicate contains of key in Map

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

Why am i able to keep duplicate contains in Map as key,
i had heart about map is :  it cat't contains duplicate keys

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;

class LinkedHasMapDemo
{
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LinkedHashMap l = new LinkedHashMap();
    //{116=kumar, 116=kumar, kumar=kumar, 117=Ram charan, 105=Yash}
    //HashMap l = new HashMap(); 
    //{116=kumar, 117=Ram charan, 116=kumar, kumar=kumar, 105=Yash}
    l.put("116","kumar");       //key is String Object
    l.put(116,"kumar");         //key is Integer Object
    l.put("kumar","kumar");
    l.put(117,"Ram charan");
    l.put(105,"Yash");
    System.out.println(l);  
}
}
```

but is in this example i am able to  keep duplicate keys in the both LinkedHashMap as well as in HashMap

Comment: Your example code has no duplicate keys.  Also, [don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).  That's probably what's confusing you.

Comment: What you think duplicate keys are? `"116"` and `116` are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, a `Map` does **not hold duplicate keys** (this only applies to keys, values can be equal). If you put a value under an already added key the previous value will be overridden. Therefore consider the following example:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("key", 1);
System.out.println(map.get("key")); // Outputs 1
System.out.println(map.size()); // Outputs 1

map.put("key", 2);
System.out.println(map.get("key")); // Outputs 2
System.out.println(map.size()); // Still outputs 1
```

The problem with your *counter-example* is that you actually **don't have duplicates** in your map.

You put `116` (an `int` or `Integer` after boxing) and `"116"` (a `String`). Since both are of **different type** the map differentiates them, they are **different objects**. Consider the following example

```
HashMap<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("116", 1);
System.out.println(map.size()); // Outputs 1

map.put(116, 2);
System.out.println(map.size()); // Now outputs 2

System.out.println("116".equals(116)); // Outputs false
```

In general you should never use **raw-types**, that is using `HashMap` without specifying the generic type to use, like `HashMap<String, Integer>`. If you don't specify anything it will use `HashMap<Object, Object>`. By that it allows every `Object` to be put into the map. In many cases you can and want to restrict this to a specific type only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have duplicates. `Integer` and `String` objects are not the same type so "116" and 116 are not equals and they have deferent Hash code

**Objects that are equal must have the same hash code within a running process**

in equals method if the type is not equals for both objects, it will return `false`, please check Integer equals implantation

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

also for Hash code they will not be equals in your case :

how String hash code is calculated :

```
 public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

And for `Integer` hash code is it the same integer value so in your case it will be 116 for `Integer` instance, so those will never be the same.

please avoid  raw-types, that is using HashMap without specifying the generic type, please read this article [what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) for more details

Comment: even if they had the same hash code, they would be considered different.

Comment: but the hash code is not relevant in this case and there is no reason to show how it is calculated. The way you explained it could be confusing and suggesting that the hash code must be diferent for the keys to be considered diferent.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String s123="123";
Integer i123=123;
System.out.println(s123.hashCode());
System.out.println(i123.hashCode());
System.out.println(i123.equals(s123)); // you can try s123.equals(i123) too
```

You can even test it online, just copy/type these lines to http://www.javarepl.com/term.html - you will see that the String has a hashcode of 48690, the Integer has 123, and they do not consider equal to each other.
(Of course it works with 116 too just I did not have that number in front of me while typing this answer)